# Counting the number of linear maps from $F_2^2 \to F_2^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to count the number of linear maps $F_2^2 \to F_2^3$. I know that there are $3$ possible bases (assuming order is irrelevant) for the domain and $28$ possible bases for the codomain.

If I imagine that linear maps are analogous to functions in that the number of functions from $A \to B$ is $|B|^{|A|}$, then this answer/guess is given by $8^6$. I am wondering if that is the right way to go about it, in terms of linear maps, however. Would we have to use the bases in some way?

I read the similar question [Counting the number of linear maps](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385454/counting-the-number-of-linear-maps), but I am assuming I only know the basic definitions of linear maps and vector spaces - matrices have yet to be defined.

Comment: Curious:  why avoid matrices?  They're like the absolute best possible tool for problems like this.  It's why they exist.

Comment: @Randall the reason is that this problem was presented in class, where we have not yet defined matrices, so I am wondering of a solution (even if is less elegant) that uses just the basic definitions

Comment: I just can't imagine a course involving linear maps between finite fields that *wouldn't* assume the student had already seen some linear algebra/matrices.  I've been wrong before, though.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found a solution at [Number of linear maps between vector spaces over finite fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/662744/number-of-linear-maps-between-vector-spaces-over-finite-fields?rq=1)

Here, our field has $2$ elements, and we map from a space of dimension $2$ to dimension $3$. So there are $2^6 = 64$ possible linear maps.

It seems like the answer just uses the idea of matrices, but expanded out as linear combinations instead of directly using matrices and isomorphisms with matrices (so @Randall was right, matrices are the best solution).